# How do I make multiple buttons that have links?

Tags: android, button, hyperlink

I have made all the buttons and all the links work just fine but the problem I am having is that i have to start from the top button and select it before proceeding to the subsequent buttons for each of those to work. In other words none one of the buttons work until I select each one in order. I'm sure I'm missing something easy here just don't know much at all about what I'm doing here. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
     package rainbow.cheetah.go.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class RainbowCheetahGOSMSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stealthychief&c=apps"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink); 



                       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.match);
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rainbow+cheetah+stealthychief&c=apps"));
                                        startActivity(myWebLink);  


                        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rainbow.cheetah.go.sms&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInJhaW5ib3cuY2hlZXRhaC5nby5zbXMiXQ.."));
                                        startActivity(myWebLink);               

                                        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter);
                                        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/Stealthychief"));
                                                        startActivity(myWebLink);






                        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.google);
                        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/u/0/105194414710791941012/posts"));
                                        startActivity(myWebLink);     }
                        });           
                  }
                });
    }


    });

    }
        });

}});

    }};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you completely messed up your parentheses. I think you meant something like this:

```
public class RainbowCheetahGOSMSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.More);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(
                        android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri
                        .parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stealthychief&c=apps"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);
            }
        });

        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.match);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rainbow+cheetah+stealthychief&c=apps"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink);
                }
        });

        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rainbow.cheetah.go.sms&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInJhaW5ib3cuY2hlZXRhaC5nby5zbXMiXQ.."));
                        startActivity(myWebLink);
                }
        });

        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitter);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/#!/Stealthychief"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink);
                }
        });

        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.google);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/u/0/105194414710791941012/posts"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink); 
                }
        });

    }
}
```